# Spring Security Question Dynamic AntMatcher based on Authenticated Role

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently trying to make dynamic AntMatcher path based on role of the authenticated user with path stored in database.

My code:

```
    @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(userAccountService, userRoleService), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
            .addFilter(new UserAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false);
}
```

Example if someone authenticated with ADMIN Role the antMatcher path will be autopopulated with allowed path in Database

My Domain:

Role.class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sec_role")
@Audited
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "access_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
    private List<Access> accessList;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "creator_username")
    private String creatorUsername;

    @Column(name = "updater_username")
    private String updaterUsername;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

Access.class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sec_access")
public class Access {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "allowedPath")
    private String allowedPath;
}
```

Is there any possible way without using any @PreAuthorized for each API or without using OAUTH2?

Any guide will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share details why do you want to generate antMatcher dynamically?

Comment: @Patel Romil It's for cleaner code and if Admin want to update which API path they need to grant they don't have to deploy a new jar file, just add new entry in database already did it